# auto creating xml template based on string pattern using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have string in below pattern

> author~time~assignedAuthor~assignedAuthor/id~assignedAuthor/addr~assignedAuthor/telecom~assignedAuthor/assignedPerson/name~

All the time the first element is root (In above string pattern it is **author**) and rest of them are child elements delemeted with character '~'. I would like to create XML using XSLT 2.0 by making use of above string pattern and I want to produce below XML.

```
<author>
    <time/>
    <assignedAuthor>
        <id/>
        <addr/>
        <telecom/>
        <assignedPerson>
            <name/>
        </assignedPerson>
    </assignedAuthor>
</author>
```

Can I have the possible solutions for this.

Comment: Why `author~time`, but `assignedAuthor~assignedAuthor/id`? Or, in other words, why `assignedAuthor` is repeated, but `author` is not? Shouldn't be `author~author/time~author/assignedAuthor~...`

Comment: I'd like to turn toxic waste into happy kittens using VBScript.

Comment: As I specified above author is a root element that is applicable for all the rest of the elements context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSegments" select=
  "tokenize(translate(/*, ' &#9;&#xA;&#xD;', ''),
            '~')
               [.]
  "/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:sequence select="my:buildXml($vSegments)"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:buildXml">
  <xsl:param name="pSegments" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:element name="{$pSegments[1]}">
    <xsl:sequence select="my:buildXml2($pSegments[position() >1])"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:buildXml2">
  <xsl:param name="pSegments" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="$pSegments"
       group-adjacent="substring-before(concat(.,'/'),'/')">
    <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:variable name="vsubSegments" select=
        "for $subSeg in current-group(),
             $subSeqTail in substring-after($subSeg, '/')
          return
             $subSeqTail[.]
        "/>
      <xsl:sequence select=
         "my:buildXml2($vsubSegments)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (using a slightly more complicated string to make this even more challenging):

```
<t>
author
   ~time
   ~assignedAuthor
   ~assignedAuthor/id
   ~assignedAuthor/addr
   ~assignedAuthor/telecom
   ~assignedAuthor/assignedPerson/name
   ~assignedAuthor/assignedPerson/address~
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<author>
   <time/>
   <assignedAuthor>
      <id/>
      <addr/>
      <telecom/>
      <assignedPerson>
         <name/>
         <address/>
      </assignedPerson>
   </assignedAuthor>
</author>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Tokenization of the sequence of "segments". Use of `tokenize()`.
2. Grouping (`xsl:for-each-group`) with the attribute `group-adjacent` using as grouping key the first "sub-segment".
3. For every group building the XML subtree recursively. Use of `current-grouping-key()` and `current-group()`

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, this is a good question and a very interesting use-case for grouping.